# Postgres: Error 28P01 and non-asked user login

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have an NodeJS app that runs ok in my dev machine, but in production have a wierd behaviour: it asks for a user that I didn't call!

Here is my .env file:

```
PGUSER=postgres
PGHOST=my.domain
PGPASSWORD=my.passwd
PGDATABASE=my.dbase
PGPORT=5432
```

As I said, it runs ok in my machine but when I try to run it in my AWS Lighsail VPS it crashes:

```
/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287
        const message = name === 'notice' ? new messages_1.NoticeMessage(length, messageValue) : new messages_1.DatabaseError(messageValue, length, name);
                                                                                                 ^

error: password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/apps/bounce/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 102,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '330',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}
```

The wierd thing: I didn't called "ubuntu" user in my code - I´m using "postgres", as in my .env file. I tried setting an user/passwd "ubuntu" and tested it , with PgAdmin and BeeKeeper - in booth apps I can access Postgres, but I couldn't do it through my Nodejs app hosted online.

My pg_hba.conf is here:

```
local all     postgres   peer
local all     ubuntu     trust
local all     all                 md5
host  all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
```

And my connectin file is here:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const conecta = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PGUSER,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    port: process.env.PGPORT
});

module.exports = conecta;
```

Why it insists in "ubuntu" user? And why my NodeJS app can't connect if PgAdmin and BeeKeeper can?

Comment: It seems like your .env file is not there, or not getting picked up, or something.  Try logging the contents of PGUSER envvar before trying to use it, to see what is going on.

Comment: My .env was in the project's root - I copied to /src folder and seems ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: use a literal call to the .env file inside `config()`:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/path/to/your/.env' });
```